# web-base system architecture

Tags: architecture, system

i wanna ask an opinion about my web system architecture.
i want to use 4-tier arch.
for client i wanna use php n mysql n html as well.
so, the user input data will b stored in myadmin database.then my jdbc connector will absorb d important data to b processed in application using java application.after that,jdbc again update the table and user can view the result.

what do u think about my architecture?is it ridiculous or imposible to make it happen?
because i dont have idea about how to run my jdbc after database updated.means, after user send data to database automatically jdbc run and query the data.this makes me stuck...

anyone any idea?

Comment: Why don't you try to stick on the same platform for the client and for the server too? for example think of having jsp with mysql for the client, and, when the request gets submitted, it could easily continue processing it. Even returning the results to the client.

Comment: do u means by using only 1-tier architecture?

Comment: No, I mean to use Java only, and have tiers all in java. That will make it possible to process the request on code-behind and return the response to the user.

Comment: gui in script?i thought of that before but seems i never learn script dats y i choose php.anyway, dats good idea thou

Answer (score 0):

Choose the best system architecture for your capability, application feature set, and available resources.

If you're new to the subject, why not pick a FOSS application you like, and take a look "under the hood" to get an idea of what best practise looks like.

Generally, picking a shopping basket stack of tech "because they're cool" is a pretty bad idea, and might put you off coding for life.

Comment: i hav done with the main application.and the thing is i dont know other language other than mysql n php+html for gui.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's possible. But, it would be a little difficult to scale out. Why don't you make a model-service tier, with Java and some Web-service lib and make PHP and the other clients (that may arise sometime) read and write from there? Then you have one single point to make changes and extend your system.

It's good what your thinking too. I've never seen though.

Comment: You're thinking about several tiers. What i'm thinking is to do a single layer just for "Data" (models, we may say). Then, to access it, you can publish a well known interface as a web service, for example. Then, instead of doing something like this from php mysql_query(con, query) just, modelService->get(...). Then, if you need to change something, you do it just at one place